# How do I map a deeply nested array object?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

In React, I have a deeply nested array (see photo) I need map over this array and retrieve the **name** and **language** which I have! but I also need to go deeper into **articles** and to retrieve the **name**, **pageSlug**, **templates** and **title** and then into **content** and retrieve data from there. How do I this in react without it getting messy?

State:

state var:

```
this.state = {
   data: []
 };
```

the api call:

```
getKnowledgePageCategories(this.props.locale).then(
      (response) => {
        this.setState({data: response})
    });
```

Array object
[image]

What I have and what works for the name prop only:

```
{data && (
    Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => {
     return (
           <ButtonGroup
             key={`${data[index].fields.name}--key`}
             name={data[index].fields.name}
             articles={}
            />
           )
         })
      )}
```

**articles** prop expects an object so I need to pass all the data from "fields" within the "articles".

Comment: "How do I this in react without it getting messy?" You probably don't. Dealing with deeply nested data structures gets messy by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to map `articles` since that's an array:

```
<ButtonGroup
  key={`${data[index].fields.name}--key`}
  name={data[index].fields.name}
  articles={data[index].fields.articles.map(article => article.fields)}
/>
```

Also, it looks like `data` is an array not an object. So no need to use `Object.keys` with it. You should be able to simply do `data.map(...`